# How to mount Physical Volumes separately which are bound using LVM

Tags: linux, centos, lvm

I have a VG (volume group) containing 3 PVs (Physical Volumes). Some physical fault has come up in one of the PVs (maybe?). 
At the attempt of mounting each PV separately, it gives `mount: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'` error. 
 
I need to check which PV is failing. Any way to do that? 
Is there any way I can separately mount the PVs to check the faulty one or is there any other solution/work-around to my problem? Thank You!

Comment: What's the output of `pvscan` ?

Comment: No matching physical volumes found

Comment: I have tried connecting each of the PV separately. pvscan gives this same output every time.

Comment: Put it in verbose mode (-vvvv)

Comment: The output http://justpaste.it/hfrh

Comment: Please check the question again. I have edited it.

Answer (score 1):

Hello I am new to this site so please be patient. My experience in this situation has been that I am better off to dd (dd if=/dev/oldDish of=/dev/newDisk) the PVs to new disks & replace the old ones. I don't generally spend to much time trying to find which disk is failing, simply because I can't risk the lose of data associated with a LVM failure. To your questions:

> I need to check which PV is failing. Any way to do that?

If you are using SATA Disks then smartctl -l error /dev/pv will give you the answer.

> Is there any way I can separately mount the PVs to check the faulty
>   one or is there any other solution/work-around to my problem?

This has already been answered above. No. The PVs are part of the LVM & can only be viewed as separated hardware (with smartctl) or as a complete LVM.

Hope my answer has been help full.

Answer (score 1):

You can't mount them individually the way you want because volumes are stripped over physical drives and it's not consistent.

As your drives are not recognized by `lvm` tools, you have to individually check them for failure.

To do so, use tools like :

- To check for bad blocks : `badblocks -v /dev/sdX`
- To check for bad response times in cached/buffered reads  `hdparm -tT /dev/sdX`

When you have identified the hard drive failing, use `hdparm -I /dev/sdX` to get the serial number of the drive.

If you use LVM mirroring you can remove it then create a new pv and re-add it in the volume group and convert the orphan linear volume back to a mirrored setup.

If you use LVM raid it should be even more simple, mark the drive as faulty then replace it and mark it as active. Then the array rebuilding process will take place.

If you don't have anything of this nor physical RAID then I hope you had a backup plan.

Answer (score 0):

Mounting just one PV of a LVM volume isn't usually possible as you have just one part of a disk available and there is not enough information to build anything mountable out of it. This is especially true if the logical volume was striped over the PVs.

That's the price you pay for the flexibility of LVM: One disk gone and you have to rebuild everything (except you use a RAID as PV). Time to test if your backup was working.

Comment: How can I figure out which PV is malfunctioning? My 3 PVs are 3 different HDs.

Comment: But can I figure out how to check if all the PVs are working fine or figure out the problem?

Comment: Strange that all your PVs appear have failed given that you are using 3 different disks.